# Sql checking if a date from 1 table is between 2 dates from different table

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have 2 sql tables

1. has Id, date, boolean value
2. has Id, date

so table 1 looks like this

```
    1 3/1/2017 false
    2 3/1/2017 true
    1 1/1/2017 false
    2 10/12/2016 false
```

table 2 like this

```
    1 3/1/2017
    2 3/1/2017
    1 2/1/2017
    1 12/12/2016
```

The result I want is for each pair of dates in table 1 that have the same id and are following each other for example for id 1 it is 1/1/2017 and 3/1/2017
to find if there is a date in table 2 with the same id that is between those dates (same day inclusive) and the boolean is false.

so for example the result in this case would be
for id1 2/1/2017, 3/1/2017

How can I do this?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result (as well formatted text.) Also show us your current query attempt. And tag the dbms you'er using.

Comment: What does "2 consecutive dates from table 1" mean?

Comment: **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: *Every* date from table2 will be between dates from table1, except those that are `< min(table1.date)` or `> max(table1.date)`.

Comment: edited the question so it is easier to understand thanks for comments

Comment: Please add the tag for the relevant rdbms

Answer (score 2):

How many rows there can be in `Table1` with the same ID? I assume 2, but the query will work reasonably even with 1 or 3+.

"are following each other" - any two dates will follow each other, unless they are the same, so the only real check below is for inequality.

"the boolean is false" - there are two rows, which can have different boolean values. I assume both of them have to be false. (false is 0, true is 1)

**Sample data**

This is how your sample data should be presented in your question. At least you should write dates in a way that we don't have to guess what is month and what is day.

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (ID int, dt date, Flag bit);
INSERT INTO @Table1 (ID, dt, Flag) VALUES
(1, '2017-01-03', 'false'),
(2, '2017-01-03', 'true'),
(1, '2017-01-01', 'false'),
(2, '2016-12-10', 'false');

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (ID int, dt date);
INSERT INTO @Table2 (ID, dt) VALUES
(1, '2017-01-03'),
(2, '2017-01-03'),
(1, '2017-01-02'),
(1, '2016-12-12');
```

**Query**

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        ID
        ,MIN(dt) AS StartDT
        ,MAX(dt) AS EndDT
        ,MAX(CAST(Flag AS int)) AS MaxFlag
    FROM @Table1 AS Table1
    GROUP BY ID
)
SELECT
    CTE.ID
    ,A.dt
FROM
    CTE
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT
            Table2.dt
        FROM @Table2 AS Table2
        WHERE
            Table2.ID = CTE.ID
            AND Table2.dt >= CTE.StartDT
            AND Table2.dt <= CTE.EndDT
    ) AS A
WHERE
    StartDT < EndDT -- "are following each other"
    AND MaxFlag = 0 -- "the boolean is false" for both IDs
;
```

**Result**

```
+----+------------+
| ID |     dt     |
+----+------------+
|  1 | 2017-01-02 |
|  1 | 2017-01-03 |
+----+------------+
```

Index on `Table2` on `(ID, dt)` will help a lot.